# Error with NaN values in input data file for Sagemaker Linear Learner model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run a Linear Regression with sagemaker.  My matrix has some null values and the linear learner algorithm is failing because of this.  Is there something I can do to make the algorithm handle null values?

Matrix data below:

```
array([[0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        1.7883900e+05, 9.6533337e+00],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        4.9014000e+04, 1.3181389e+01],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        1.2483900e+05, 1.1561944e+01],
       ...,
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        4.7306000e+04, 1.8681944e+01],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        1.3530000e+04, 1.1964444e+01],
       [0.0000000e+00,           nan,           nan, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        8.4100000e+03, 1.8925833e+01]], dtype=float32)
```

## Run the model

```
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
role = get_execution_role()
linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[boto3.Session().region_name],
                                       role, 
                                       train_instance_count=1, 
                                       train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                                       output_path=output_location,
                                       sagemaker_session=sess)

#Model Parameters
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=25,
                           predictor_type='regressor',
                           normalize_data=False)

linear.fit({'train': s3_train_data})
linear_predictor = linear.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                                 instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

> Blockquote

Output:

```
2019-08-16 12:40:21 Starting - Starting the training job...
2019-08-16 12:40:24 Starting - Launching requested ML instances......
2019-08-16 12:41:23 Starting - Preparing the instances for training......
2019-08-16 12:42:34 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2019-08-16 12:43:15 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress.
2019-08-16 12:43:15 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2019-08-16 12:43:15 Failed - Training job failed

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job linear-learner-2019-08-16-12-40-21-312: Failed. Reason: ClientError: Unable to read data channel 'train'. Found missing (NaN) values. Please remove any missing (NaN) values in the input data. (caused by MXNetError)

Caused by: [12:43:11] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsCppLibs/AIAlgorithmsCppLibs-2.0.1649.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/aialgs/io/iterator_base.cpp:103: (Input Error) (NaN) NaN value encountered in the dataset.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, You are going to have to clean any rows that contain missing values for SageMaker to be able to process them.

Seeing as how your case looks like continuous values, your best option would be to remove them.

If the empty values are important to your data, you could try to factorize those columns into discrete values so that the nulls become part of the data. This would be dependent on the data, and wouldn't be very recommended if those columns have a lot of variation.